# How to clear previous presentation of data in the listView (on ListFragment extend), which is populated by custom array adapter

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I did try methods as "adapter.clear", "adapter.invalidate", adapter.notifyDataSetChanged" and other suggestions - nothing works. Basicly I have one calling fragment activity with the spiner on it where paths to the some files are settled - when element in the spinner gets selected, fragment with list view is presented. The problem is, when in the next itearation array is populated with fewer items as it was previously, the list item present this new elements, but those from older array also.
t's pain in the .... Anyone has solution for this?

**activity class**

```
public class ListBitmapsFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ListBitmapsFragment.Callbacks {
// variable spinner to show values for the paths to the images
Spinner s1;
// variable of ArrayAdapter class to hold the values of the possible picture file paths for the spinner
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
// variable of the ArrayList class to store the values of possible picture paths
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // set the content
    setContentView(R.layout.list_bitmap_fragment_activity);
    // setting adapter for the spinner widget
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
    s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    // set some possible paths to the images in the adapter for the spinner
    adapter.add("SELECT THE PATH TO THE PICTURES:");
    adapter.add("storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/");
    adapter.add(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("DCIM/")
            .getAbsolutePath());
    adapter.add(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
    // set listener for the spinner
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int id, long position) {
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(22);
            String pathValue = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (!(pathValue == "SELECT THE PATH TO THE PICTURES:")) {
                callTheFragment(pathValue);
            }
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
// overriden method from the inner interface within the fragment class
public void onBitmapSelected(String imagePath) {
    // communicate the result of the clicked row in the fragment class to the calling activity
    Intent i = new Intent();
    // use the putExtra() method to return some value to the calling activity---
    i.putExtra("path", imagePath);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();
}

public void callTheFragment(String pathValue) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.item_list);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("pathValue", pathValue);
    // if fragment is not present on it's container
    if (fragment == null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragment = new ListBitmapsFragment();
        // set the object of arguments to the fragment
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.add(R.id.item_list, fragment);
        // add fragment to the stack in case of using back button to recall the fragment
        // ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

}

**fragment clas which extends ListFragment**

```
public class ListBitmapsFragment extends ListFragment {
private Callbacks mCallbacks;

public interface Callbacks {
    public void onBitmapSelected(String path);
}

private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapSelected(String imagePath) {
    }
};

public ListBitmapsFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), pathArray()));
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Klicoca aktivnost mora implementirati callback!!");
    }
    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
    View row = view;
    TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.imagePath);
    mCallbacks.onBitmapSelected(tv.getText().toString());
}

private List<String> pathArray() {
    String rootPath = getArguments().getString("pathValue");
    final List<String> directoryEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
    File directory = new File(rootPath);
    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
            public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                return -Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(
                        f2.lastModified());
            }
        });
        directoryEntries.clear();
        for (File file : files) {
            directoryEntries.add(file.getPath());
        }
    }
    if (directoryEntries.isEmpty()) {
        directoryEntries.add("storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/no_photo.jpg");
    }
    return directoryEntries;
}

class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final List<String> paths;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity context, List<String> paths) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_bitmap_paths, paths);
        this.context = context;
        this.paths = paths;
    }

    class ViewContainer {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView txtPath;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewContainer viewContainer;
        View rowView = view;
        Bitmap unscaledBitmap;
        Bitmap scaledBitmap;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_bitmap_paths, null,
                    true);
            viewContainer = new ViewContainer();
            viewContainer.txtPath = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imagePath);
            viewContainer.imageView = (ImageView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.icon);
            rowView.setTag(viewContainer);
        } else {
            viewContainer = (ViewContainer) rowView.getTag();
        }
        viewContainer.txtPath.setText(this.paths.get(position));
        viewContainer.imageView.setImageBitmap(null);

        unscaledBitmap = ScalingUtilities.decodeFile(
                this.paths.get(position), 100, 100, ScalingLogic.FIT);
        scaledBitmap = ScalingUtilities.createScaledBitmap(unscaledBitmap,
                100, 100, ScalingLogic.FIT);
        viewContainer.imageView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(238, 233, 233));
        } else {
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can removeAllViews() from the actual ListView and not just clear the adapter... try

```
((ListBitmapsFragment)fragment).getListView().removeAllViews()
```

Comment: Hi Atomix, I'll try and will post feedback.

Comment: This method is not supported and throws an UnsupportedOperationException when called.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Atomix, I have found the solution for this problem - in the method callTheFragment() I've made some changes: I used the information about the fragment in the container and upon it I had deleted it, if it would had exixsted and along with that I did find ViewGroup (container) fro the fragment and clear all it's views. And it works.
Thanks,
Erik D.

```
    public void callTheFragment(String pathValue) {
    // set the object for the fragment manager
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    // set object of the fragment class - container for the fragment
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.item_list);
    // if there is a fragment allready in the container
    if (!(fragment == null)) {
        // remove the existing fragment
        fm.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
        // get reference to the parrent container
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.item_list);
        // delete all views from the parrent container
        vg.removeAllViews();
    }
    // new fragment
    // object of variables for pass them to the fragment
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("pathValue", pathValue);
    // FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragment = new ListBitmapsFragment();
    // set the object of arguments to the new fragment
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    // execute transaction
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.item_list, fragment).commit();
}
```